# R types of ants live in a place. Find the expected values.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables, expected-value

$R$ types of ants live in a place. A person is catching ants until he picks an ant of type $1$. Since the number of ants in the area is high, you can assume that picking a new ant each time is independent from the previous time. Picking an ant of type $i$ has the probability $P_i$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^R P_i = 1$.

1) Find the expected value of the number of ants he picks before picking an ant of type $1$.

2) Find the expected value of the number of ant types he picks before picking an ant of type $1$.

My attempts:

Here's my alleged solution for the first one:

1) What is the probability for the outcome that he picks $m$ ants before picking an ant of type $1$? Well, he has to pick $m$ ants from any type but type $1$ and the last time he has to pick an ant of type $1$. So, the probability (because of independence) is $(1-P_1)^m\times P_1$ and the expected value is therefore given by:

$$\mathbb{E}(X)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nP_1(1-P_1)^n=P_1\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(1-P_1)^n=\frac{P_1(1-P_1)}{P_1^2}=\frac{1-P_1}{P_1}$$

Is this correct?

2) I'm stuck. I think that maybe I should define $X_i$ for $1,\cdots, R$ to be the random variable that shows whether we have picked an ant of type $i$ or not. Then, $X = \sum_{i=2}^R X_i$ and then I can study the expectation of $X_i$. But I don't know how to proceed from here. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

So, $\mathbb{E}(X_i)$ is equal to the probability of picking an ant of type $i$ during the whole process. Let's call it $\pi_i$. Calculating $\pi_i$ seems difficult, so I will calculate its complement $1-\pi_i$, i.e. I never see an ant of type $i$. I think $1-\pi_i$ is equal to the following:

$$1-\pi_i = P_1 + (1-P_1-P_i)\times P_1 + (1-P_1-P_i)^2\times P_1 + \dots + (1-P_1-P_i)^n\times P_1$$
$$1-\pi_i = P_1 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (1-P_1-P_i)^n = P_1 \times \frac{1}{P_1+P_i}$$

$$\pi_i = 1-\frac{P_1}{P_1+P_i} = \frac{P_i}{P_1+P_i}$$

And therefore, $$\mathbb{E}(X) = \sum_{i=2}^R \pi_i$$

Comment: An easy way to see the first one:    Consider the first ant.  If it is type I, you are done (and the answer on that trial is $0$).  If not, you restart.  Thus $E=P_1\times 0+(1-P_1)\times (1+E)\implies E=\frac {1-P_1}{P_1}$.

Comment: Your idea for the second part is good.  All you need to do to finish is to compute the probability that type $i$ is chosen before type $1$.  You can do that along the same line as in my first comment.

Comment: Because you have taken one turn already.

Comment: should it not be $P_1 \times 1$ since you always pick one ant, you could never have ana answer zero if P was 1

Comment: @Cato  If you draw an ant of type I first, then you chose $0$ ants prior to getting an ant of type $1$.  This is the usual confusion on the geometric distribution.  Some times you count the successful trial, other times (as here) you don't.

Comment: if there was only one type of ant, you'd get E = 0, not E = 1, you've always got to pick an ant though

Comment: @Cato, to repeat;  we are asked to count the number of ants chosen BEFORE the first ant of type I.  If the first draw is of type I, then the answer is $0$.  If all the ants are of type I, then every trial gives $0$ for this count.

Comment: Yes, $X_i$ is just the indicator variable and its expectation is just the probability.  Indicator variables almost always have expectation less than $1$.

Comment: Oh, I wouldn't expect the sum to be less than $1$.  It depends on $P_1$.  If $P_1$ is low, then you expect many ants to be chosen before you get the first one of type $1$...in which case the sum would have to be at least $1$.

Comment: If that's literally what they mean by 'before' then I agree, but I took it to include the final ant he picks.  He has to pick an ant before he can identify it.

Comment: for the second one, on each pick you can calculate the probability an ant type has been picked, which you can sum, then sum the picks and the probability it ends there

Comment: I don't understand your computation.  If $i\neq 1$ then let's compute $\pi_i$, the probability that you get type $i$ before you get type $1$.  Consider the first ant drawn.  There are three possible outcomes:  you get type $1$, you get type $i$, you get some other type.  Thus $\pi_i=P_1\times 0 +P_i\times 1+(1-P_1-P_i)\times \pi_i\implies \pi_i=\frac {P_i}{P_1+P_i}$.  As a cheap sanity check, note that $P_i=P_1\implies \pi_i=\frac 12$ as it should.

Comment: Should have added:  if you take $P_1=\frac 12=P_i$ then of course we should have $\pi_i=\frac 12$ by symmetry.  But your formula gives $1$.

Comment: Informally:  to compute $\pi_i$ we can ignore all the types besides types $i$ and $1$.  Thus we only need to think about the $P_1+P_i$ part of the probability universe that restricts to those two type.  Once you are in that part of the universe, it's only a question of what the first draw is...which, I think, makes the formula intuitively clear.

Comment: Yes, it looks good now...but I strongly recommend running sanity checks for all calculations of this sort.  They are terribly error prone (for all of us, not just you).  Also, I recommend looking at arguments that avoid geometric series.  In my experience, when the series work it is always possible to avoid using them.  And using them complicates the algebra.

Comment: Yes, the sum should avoid $X_1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

For Part I:  Let $E$ denote the answer.  Consider the first ant drawn.  There are two possible outcomes...either you get type I (in which case the outcome is $0$ for that trial) or you don't (in which case the expected outcome is now $1+E$).  Thus $$E=P_1\times 0 +(1-P_1)\times (1+E)\implies E=\frac {1-P_1}{P_1}$$

For Part II: Let $\mathbb E$ denote the answer. for $i>1$ we let $X_i$ be the indicator variable for ants of type $i$.  Thus $X_i=1$ if you see type $i$ before type $1$ and $0$ otherwise.  Then $$\mathbb E=E\left[ \sum X_i\right]=\sum E\left[ X_i\right]=\sum \pi_i$$

Where $\pi_i$ denotes the probability that type $i$ is seen before type $1$.

To compute $\pi_i$ we again consider the consequences of a single draw.  There are three possible outcomes:  we see type $1$, we see type $i$, we see some other type.  Thus $$\pi_i=P_1\times 0+P_i\times 1+(1-P_1-P_i)\times \pi_i\implies \pi_i=\frac {P_i}{P_1+P_i}$$

Sanity check:  if $P_1=P_i$ this gives $\frac 12$ as it should.

Thus $$\mathbb E=\sum_{i>1}\frac {P_i}{P_1+P_i}$$

Comment: Should your denominator for $\pi_i$ be $P_1+P_i$ rather than $P_1+P_2$?

Comment: @paw88789  Absolutely.  Thanks.  I'll edit.